# Is slickgrid supports only json and xml formats.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slickgrid

Is slickgrid supports only json and xml formats.
I want to implement the slickgrid in rails 3.x
my data's are in hash format?
any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your Ruby objects to JSON, feed SlickGrid with that JSON data.